# Passing stateless element to JS function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, stateless

I'm trying to build a ReactJS app and my current app is using redux so all our components are stateless consts.

I'm trying to integrate a JS theme which will work if I use standard Components because you pass the element to the function in componentDidMount, e.g.:

```
import p from '../test/ui/jsTheme'

class Component extends React.Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    new p.Bar(this.el)
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <nav ref={el => this.el = el} className="bar"">
           ...
        </nav>
    )
  }
```

But I'm using redux and components are actually defined stateless consts like:

```
import React from 'react';

export const AppNav = props => {

  if (props.loading) {
    return (
      <div>
          <div className="progress">
              Loading
          </div>
      </div>
    );
  } else {
    return (
      <nav>
      ...
      </nav>
    )
  }
```

)

I've tried a few things but I have no luck in passing the const as an element which is what the JS theme is expecting to the new p.Bar(this.el) constructor

Any ideas?!

Comment: What is stopping you to create a statefull component. refs cannot be added for stateless component

Comment: Probably nothing but so far all our components are consts which are connected in a container with redux, so was hoping not to rework all our components (also not sure if that effects how redux will then work)